# How do I test if a variable is a string in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I tried the following but without success

```
[root@OBAMA~]# bash
[root@OBAMA~]# a=HelloWorld

[root@OBAMA~]# [[ $a == [A-Za-z] ]] && echo "YES ITS STRING"
```

( the command not prints anything )

```
[root@OBAMA~]# [[ $a == [A-Z][a-z] ]] && echo "YES ITS STRING"
```

( the command not prints anything )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your command lke below.

```
$ [[ $a =~ [A-Za-z]+ ]] && echo "YES ITS STRING"
YES ITS STRING
```

- Use `=~` operator to test an input string against a regex.
- Add `+` next to the character class, so that it would repeat the previous  pattern or token one or more times. Here it's unnecessary.

Add anchors , in-order to do an exact string match. `[[ $a =~ [A-Za-z] ]] && echo "YES ITS STRING"` alone will print the string `YES ITS STRING` because the variable `a` contains atleast an alphabet.

```
$ a="HelloWorld"
$ [[ $a =~ ^[A-Za-z]+$ ]] && echo "YES ITS STRING"
YES ITS STRING
$ a="Hello World"
$ [[ $a =~ ^[A-Za-z]+$ ]] && echo "YES ITS STRING"
$
```

Answer (score 1):

how do you define "a string"

```
[[ -n $a ]] && echo variable a is not empty

[[ $a == *[[:alpha:]]* ]] && echo variable a contains a letter

shopt -s extglob failglob
[[ $a == +([[:alpha:]]) ]] && echo variable a only has letters
```

Your glob expressions are not matching because your checking that your variable contains only 1 character or 2 characters.

Comment: how do you define "a string" --> string  must include only chars ( A-Z /a-z )

Comment: choose between Avinash's anchored regular expression or my extended glob, both will satisfy that requirement